# Python - __str__ returning elements of a list

Tags: python, class, return

I have two classes, lets call them A and B. Now A is supposed to print out the card values, like

```
def __str__(self):
    return (str(self.value) + self.suit)
3H #This is what is returned.
```

and that works fine, but my problem is trying to get B to display properly. I need to to return

```
'Players Card's 3H 4H (Total 7)' #This whole line is supposed to be printed
```

Im having troubles with what to write under the __str_ part and so that I can get it to print out the value of A but in the format needed to B.

Edit: So class B will have a list, lets call it hand, and that list has the class objects of class A, which are card objects of the format '3H' so a hand may look like this:

```
hand = ['3H', '4H']
```

and I would want to print it out such as class A does but in class B's __str_

Comment: Some more information about the B class will be necessary to help with this.

Comment: Or more explicitly, show us the code of class B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your `Card` class:

```
class Card(object):
    # has self.value and self.suit

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.value) + self.suit)
```

So your player class is something like this:

```
class Player(object):
    # has self.card1, self.card2

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player's Cards %s %s (Total %d)" % (
            self.card1, self.card2, self.__sum_of_cards()
        )
```

So, all you need is to add the missing method `__sum_of_cards` in `Player`:

```
def __sum_of_cards(self):
    return self.card1.value + self.card2.value
```

You could do this directly in `__str__` instead of implementing `__sum_of_cards`, but I'm assuming it means something if you're printing it, and that implies it will be needed elsewhere as well.

### Edit:

Same goes for lists:

```
class Player(object):
    # has self.hand

    def __str__(self):
        return "Player's Cards %s (Total %d)" % (
            ",".join(str(card) for card in self.hand),
                     self.__sum_of_hand()
        )
```

But a different `__sum_of_hand` is needed:

```
def __sum_of_hand(self):
    return sum(x.value for x in self.hand)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm not sure of what self.card1 is. If its not clear above let me say it again, class A prints it out properly with the '3H' , but I want to be able to print class A but in class B. Also, using your code, we run into the error of the player getting another card, and there being more than 2 cards to print

Comment: I somehow assumed you have two cards. See edit. You **are** calling `__str__` in `Card` by doing `"%s" % a_object`. Do you have a list of `Card` objects or `str`s?

Comment: Yes, I saw your edit right after I posted my comment. I am working on your second approach now. Ill post back if I get it. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated. It is a list of card objects